# LeafletJs Add Nexrad Radar To Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add radar nexrad to map with leafletjs these are my code.
After Adding these code i don't see nothing on the map.

My website: https://severestormsmedia.com/map

````
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '&copy; severestormsmedia.com',
    maxZoom: 4.1,
    id: 'mapbox/dark-v10',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9leWNyZWF0b3IiLCJhIjoiY2tva253dHRxMDFhMzJubzF0NmNidTV1byJ9.fuQQQ11Nb0tnr-jbWemOsQ'
}).addTo(mymap);

var subs = ["mesonet", "mesonet1", "mesonet2", "mesonet3"];
var nexrad = L.tileLayer.wms("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0q.cgi", {
    layers: 'nexrad-n0r-900913',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: false,
    attribution: "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
}).addTo(mymap);```
````

Comment: If you spend a bit of time with your browser's [debugging tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), you'll be able to see that the WMS server is replying with XML messages containing the string `Invalid layer(s) given in the LAYERS parameter.`.

Comment: Ok, But what suppose to be the layers i search on google . raster

Comment: Pal, start with the WMS tutorial at https://leafletjs.com/examples.html .